# Rendering external handlebars in routes

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

So I've been working with ember for the last 3 month but I still have some doubts about rendering external handlebars.

So suppose that I've the following handlebar in a file called about.handlebars

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="about">
   <div> About Page </div>
</script>
```

So I've the following route:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('about');
});

App.AboutRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('About');
  }
});
```

How can I render this template if it’s in an external file?

Comment: you can't, you need to preprocess your templates first, then they will be available in the Ember.TEMPLATES array. do you use any build tool for your project?

Comment: Hi, thanks.. when you say "do you use any build tool for your projec?" what have you in mind? can you give me some examples?

Comment: by that I mean tools like yeoman, or grunt directly. these tools include the possibility to pre compile the templates so you can put them in external files and reference them later in your app

Comment: Not, but I'll search to learn more about these tools. Thanks

Comment: have a look at http://jaketrent.com/post/precompile-ember-templates/ This should give you a good idea on how to use grunt with ember.